# Refreshing simple list (android, adapter)

Tags: android, list, adapter

I'm not sure if i made good title (still new in android).

Question:
If I make function:

```
    public void refresh_lists() {
    // wyswietlanie listy miesiecy
    ArrayAdapter<String> month_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, miesiac_data);
    month_list_v.setAdapter(month_adapter);

    // wyswietlanie listy dni
    ArrayAdapter<String> daily_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dzien_data);
    daily_list_v.setAdapter(daily_adapter);
}
```

(`miesiac_data` and `dzien_data` are `String` arrays)
Then remake arrays somewhere else, like:

```
miesiac_data[] = new String[new_length];
dzien_data[] = new String[new_length];
```

Then add new records to arrays and finally, add `refresh_list` function as `onClick()` effect, does it create new lists everytime I push button, or just refreshes old ones?

Comment: What you mean "create new lists" or "refresh old ones".  Are you talking about the String arrays?

Comment: um, hard to explain (i lack words lol..):
With lists i mean ArrayAdapters, which show simple lists on device (simple list = http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/simple-android-listview.png).

not sure if i made it clearer now :|

Comment: Then use daily_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().  This tells the adapter that the underlying data (your String[]) has changed.  The adapter will refresh itself and in turn, the ListView which is bound to it.

Comment: not sure if i used it as it should be. I call daily_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after recreation of arrays with new entries, so it should display new content, but it shows only old one. (Tho, new content is in array for sure, i checked it via log..)

Comment: Ah, sorry.I see now.  notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add,delete etc methods of the ArrayAdapter.  use daily_adapter = new ArrayAdapter again or change your code to use the ArrayAdapter data modification methods.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426